# Saving values in a vector inside a loop, and finding the specific loop at which a certain element is saved

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, indexing, location

I have a code that calculates the minimum distance between two line segments by discretizing t, and s between 0 and 1 with h. The code saves the distance for each value of s and t in a vector and the smallest value is picked out at the end.

I would like to find the corresponding t and s for which the minimum distance occurs. For example, if the minimum distance is located at index 3000 in the 'mindist' vector, which value of t and s does this correspond?

Thanks in advance!
/Arian

Edit: I provided the entire code with some comments aswell. I've changed it a bit and this seems to do the trick:

```
% Start and end points of line segments
P0=[-0.43256 -1.6656 0.12533]; 
P1=[0.28768 -1.1465 1.1909]; 
Q0=[1.1892 -0.037633 0.32729]; 
Q1=[0.17464 -0.18671 0.72579];

% Direction vectors
u=P1-P0; 
v=Q1-Q0;
w0=P0-Q0;

% Dot products
a=dot(u,u);
b=dot(u,v);
c=dot(v,v);
d=dot(u,w0);
e=dot(v,w0);
F=a*c-b^2;

h=0.01;
t=0:h:1;
s=0:h:1;
mindist=[];
for i=1:length(t)
    for j=1:length(s)
        if F==0
            t(i)=e/c;
            mindist(i,j)=norm((P0+s(j)*u)-(Q0+t(i)*v));
        else
            mindist(i,j)=norm((P0+s(j)*u)-(Q0+t(i)*v));
        end
    end
end
[minval,loc]=min(mindist(:));
[i, j] = ind2sub(size(mindist), loc);
minval=norm((P0+s(j)*u)-(Q0+t(i)*v))
```

minval =

```
1.0710
```

Comment: Isn't it more efficient to only save the minimum, and the position?

Comment: Please provide a runnable example (i.e. make sure that all variables are defined), or at the very least some representative input and output(s). See also: [mcve]. What's wrong with your code? Also, what makes you so sure that nested loops are the best approach here (... perhaps it could be solved using vectorization)? It's good to make sure that you're asking about _a problem_ and not about _a solution_. See also: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: Provided the entire code now and some changes to it that seems to do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not need nested cycles, thanks to Matlab's `pdist2()` function. Here is an example:

```
h=0.01;

% Random vectors
P0 = [0;0];
Q0 = [0;2];
u  = [1;0];
v  = [0.707 ; -0.707];

t = 0:h:1;  % Do not really need "s"

U = P0+t.*u;
V = Q0+t.*v;
% The lines above work in Matlab 2016b and beyond. For older versions use:
% U = P0 + [t.*u(1) ; t.*u(2)];
% V = Q0 + [t.*v(1) ; t.*v(2)];

d = pdist2(U',V');  % Pairwise distance between two sets of observations

[min_dist , position] = min2(d);

% Plot problem and result
figure
plot([P0(1) , P0(1)+u(1)] , [P0(2) , P0(1)+u(2)] , 'r-')
hold on;  axis equal;
plot([Q0(1) , Q0(1)+v(1)] , [Q0(2) , Q0(2)+v(2)] , 'g-')
plot([U(1,position(1)) , V(1,position(2))] , [U(2,position(1)) V(2,position(2))] , 'b-')
title(['Minimal distance: ' num2str(min_dist) '. t=' num2str(t(position(1))) '. s = ' num2str(t(position(2)))])
legend('Vector 1' , 'Vector 2' , 'Shortest distance')
```

Comment: Emm, nice insight, but it seems that your code has some typo. `t` is a 1x101 vector and `u` is a 2x1, so we can't run `t.*u`.

Comment: It works in Matlab 2016b. They changed array operations in this version. More info [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/). In older versions you could use `U = P0 + [t.*u(1) ; t.*u(2)];`

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Works very well